# Batch convert text to audio files, retaining file names

Tags: mac

I have a folder with hundreds of text files. I'd like to batch convert them to audio files but make sure each audio file retains the file name of the text file From which it was created.

I am newer to Mac, so this is proving difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify an audio format but try the following in terminal in the directory containing your text files.

```
for f in *.txt;do say -f "$f" -o "${f%txt}aif";done
```

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/709935/mac-osx-text-to-speech-batch) on superuser for other solutions.

Comment: fyi - basically this is saying "for every `.txt` file in this directory, use Apple's `say` command to record your Mac `say`ing the contents of that text file into a file of the same name but with an `aif` extension instead of a `txt` extension".

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I needed with a useful explanation to boot. Major thanks!